# iptables: How to redirect / forward traffic without traffic through server?

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I now played around with iptables (the whole day) to make my rules work, but there is one issue.. all traffic that I redirect goes through my server and back through my server. We are talking about high HIGH amounth of bandwidth. So I hoped there was a option to redirect a user to the external global IP, so it talkes to the external IP and the users IP directly.

I now did:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 11.111.11.111:25

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

*this is just a example, the real project is not port 25 and is also a other program (we work on...)

But now all traffic goes like this User>MyServer>ExternalServer>MyServer>User

but i hoped to get something like this:
User>MyServer>ExternalServer>User

Simular to CNAME or maybe htacces redirect.
Is something like this even possible?

Comment: As often: why? What do you want to achieve? You're speaking of port 25/tcp - why don't you set your MX accordingly? Or configure your clients appropriately?

Comment: Ok yes true, this was just a example, the real project is not port 25, but some other port and program. But for the example I thought it would not matter..

Comment: It might matter. How are "MyServer" and "ExternalServer" correlated? Is the LVS approach of mgorven applicable? If not, then there is no possible way of achieving, what you want instead of protocol features. Like http's redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want an xinetd redirect, not an iptables one (I've never needed to do this in anger). Try this:

```
# /etc/xinetd.d/redirect25
service redirect25
{
        port                    = 25
        type                    = UNLISTED
        disable                 = no
        socket_type             = stream
        wait                    = no
        user                    = root
        redirect                = 11.111.11.111 25
}
```

then restart xinetd. You might need to consider relay issues given that this is the mail port.

Comment: ok thx! I'll try this! but i did not succeed with xinetd last time because i use a port that is not used by any deamon.. (port 25 was a example but i use a other port on my real website) so I don't know if that caused the issue.. but i will try it again! thx

Comment: did you use UNLISTED?

Comment: yes i used  " type = UNLISTED "

Comment: also my iptables look like this: iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: This still proxies all traffic.

Comment: ah ok, i always get xinetd redirects and iptables -J redirect confused.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use something like [Linux Virtual Server](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/) with the [LVS/TUN](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-IPTunneling.html) or [LVS/DR](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-DRouting.html) methods. These create a virtual IP on a load balancer, which then tunnels or directly routes incoming packets to backend servers while preserving the original source and destination IP (unlike NAT). The backend servers can then route the response packets directly to the client and not via the load balancer.

I don't think that this can be done with iptables alone.

Comment: WO! Mgorven... you brought me on a good possible solution!! i need to read more ofcourse but the images in the example looks very promising.